# Rails 4: Ajax request calls function and returns value without redirect

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rails controller function that calls out to a model function to fetch data and return that data.  I am trying to use ajax to make the function call and don't want any redirect as all I care about are the values being returned.  **How can I accomplish this without reloading the page / getting a missing template error?**

**Controller**

```
def update_sales
    @data = ControllerName.function_name()
    return @data  # What I want
    redirect_to path_name # what I don't want
end
```

**Model**

```
def self.function_name
    ...
    ...
    return data
end
```

**Ajax**

```
$.get("/update_sales").done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    // I would set html attribute to data but I get missing template error
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could try something like this in controller action?

```
 if @data.save
   // send the object back to interface
   render json: @data.serialize.to_json, status: :ok
 else
   // send the errors back to interface
   render json: @data.errors.full_messages, status: :internal_server_error
 end
```

ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
    url:"/update_sales",
    type: "PATCH",
    data: data_to_send
  }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // do stuff when it is done
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    // do stuff if it errors out
  });
```

Comment: Great!  I removed the `.save` portion and just verified that `@data` was present, but this worked like a charm